# How to reinit login?

Tags: authentication, init, pgadmin-4

I installed pgadmin 4 two days ago on ubuntu.
I forgot the password and nothing can reinit it.
pip uninstall and pip install  keeps the previous login.
smtp server is not install on my PC so the recover password fails.

Where is the config file to reinit pgAdmin ?
I used the file pgadmin4-2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl

Answer (score 0):

Just search for `pgadmin4.db` file and delete it, Now restart pgAdmin4 and check, it should ask you new username and password on startup.